# Any way to use html.Parse without it adding nodes to make a 'well-formed tree'?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/html"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "Blah. <b>Blah.</b> Blah."
    n, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Parse error: %s", err)
    }
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    if err := html.Render(&buf, n); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Render error: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

Output:

```
<html><head></head><body>Blah. <b>Blah.</b> Blah.</body></html>
```

Is there a way to stop `html.Parse` from making a document out of fragments (ie avoid adding `<html>`, `<body>` etc.)?  I'm aware of [`html.ParseFragment`](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/html#ParseFragment) but it seems to exhibit the same behaviour.

You can get around it by wrapping the text to be parsed with a parent element such as `<span>` then doing something like the following:

```
n = n.FirstChild.LastChild.FirstChild
```

but that seems, well, kludgy to say the least.

Ideally I'd like to: accept input, manipulate or remove nodes found within it, and write the result back to a string, even if the result is an incomplete document.

Comment: Note the existance of [`goquery`](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) which could be handy for the tasks you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, and for completeness I'll mention again Jeremy's [go-html-transform](https://code.google.com/p/go-html-transform) which I've used in the past. I'm trying to get to grips with exp/html (now go.net/html) which seems likely to make it into the standard library around version 1.2 or so, but it's good to see these third party projects emerging too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to provide a context to ParseFragment. The following program prints out the original text:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/html"
    "code.google.com/p/go.net/html/atom"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "Blah. <b>Blah.</b> Blah."
    n, err := html.ParseFragment(strings.NewReader(s), &html.Node{
        Type:     html.ElementNode,
        Data:     "body",
        DataAtom: atom.Body,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Parse error: %s", err)
    }
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    for _, node := range n {
        if err := html.Render(&buf, node); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Render error: %s", err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried to use context, but clearly I screwed something up. This is just what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this, 4 years later.

Answer (score 6):

You want http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/html#ParseFragment. Pass in a fake Body element as your context and the fragment will be returned as a slice of just the elements in your fragment.

You can see an example in the Partial* functions for go-html-transform's go.net/html wrapper package. https://code.google.com/p/go-html-transform/source/browse/h5/h5.go#32